# Is there a way to use conda to install libraries in a Docker image?

Tags: docker, anaconda, dockerfile, conda, pytorch

I'm trying to install some libraries (specifically pytorch) in my docker image.  I have a Dockerfile that installs anaconda properly, but now I'd like to use conda to install a few other things in the image.  Is there a way to do this?  I've tried

RUN /opt/anaconda/bin/conda install -y pytorch torchvision

And anaconda is installed in the right location.  Am I doing this the right way?

Comment: Yes? What error message do you have? What is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

First, check if the way you have added/installed anaconda in your own image reflects the [`ContinuumIO/docker-images/anaconda`](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/docker-images/blob/master/anaconda/Dockerfile).

Second, you can test the installation dynamically, as the README recommends

```
docker run -it yourImage /bin/bash -c "/opt/conda/bin/conda install ...
```

If that is working correctly, you can do the same in your Dockerfile.